# Saving Object to IsolatedStorage in WP7 with XNA 4.0

Tags: windows-phone-7, serialization, xna, xna-4.0

How can I go about saving an object of type `GameSettings` to `IsolatedStorage` on a Windows Phone 7 application made with XNA 4.0?

From what I can tell, you can't flag a class as serializable and `ByteFormatter` isn't available. I haven't come across a good way to convert an object to a byte array and write the array to the storage. And going beyond that, I have no idea how to go about converting said byte array back into an object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why can't you mark it as serializable? Why must you save it as a byte array?

Comment: Well, I wanted to serialize an object to a file but I didn't want to do it by making an XML document and saving that. It would just not build with the `[Serializable]` tag. I presume that it does not exist for Windows PHone 7?

Comment: In any case, I ended up not needing that but I'd like to keep the question open because I'm curious as to how one would serialize an object (without XML or JSON since binary is reportedly quicker) on WP7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in binary formatter on the platform but it does support XML and JSON serialization using the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) classes.

You can configure what is serialized via the [DataContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and [DataMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) attributes.